# RSpec Testing to return Favorited Posts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am new to Ruby on Rails and am currently enrolled in a course at Bloc.io that has tasked me with creating RSpec tests that return whether or not a post has been favorited by a specific user.

Here is my current RSpec file:

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe User do

 include TestFactories

 describe "#favorited(post)" do

   before do
     @post = associated_post
     @user = authenticated_user
   end

   it "returns `nil` if the user has not favorited the post" do
     expect( @user.favorited(@post) ).to be_nil
   end

   it "returns the appropriate favorite if it exists" do
     favorite = Favorite.new
     expect( @user.favorite ).to eq( favorited(@post) )
   end

   it "returns `nil` if the user has favorited another post" do

   end
  end
 end
```

I have been successful in passing the first test(`it "returns 'nil' if the user has not favorited the post"`), but am stumped on how to get the second and third tests to pass.

I think what I currently have started for the second test (`it "returns 'nil' if the user has not favorited the post"`) is correct and believe I need to supply a hash to `Favorite.new` that would assign it to a post and a user, but am unsure what would need to be passed in.

Here is my included `TestFactories` file just incase that helps:

```
module TestFactories

 def associated_post(options={})
   post_options = {
     title: 'Post title',
     body: 'Post bodies must be pretty long.',
     topic: Topic.create(name: 'Topic name'),
     user: authenticated_user
     }.merge(options)

    Post.create(post_options)
 end

 def authenticated_user(options={})
   user_options = {email: 'email#{rand}@fake.com', password: 'password'}.merge(options)
   user = User.new(user_options)
   user.skip_confirmation!
   user.save
   user
 end

end
```

as well as my `#favorited(post)` method:

```
def favorited(post)
  favorites.where(post_id: post.id).first
end
```

EDIT:

Here is the Favorite Model:

```
class Favorite < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :user
end
```

2nd EDIT:

I was able to change a bit of my code for my second test:

```
it "returns the appropriate favorite if it exists" do
  favorite = Favorite.create(user: @user, post: @post)
  expect( @user.favorited(@post) ).to eq( favorite )
end
```

I am now receiving the following failure/error:

```
Failures:

1) User#favorited(post) returns the appropriate favorite if it exists
   Failure/Error: expect( @user.favorited(@post) ).to eq( favorite )

   expected: #<Favorite id: 1, post_id: 1, user_id: nil, created_at: "2015-04-26 04:16:37", updated_at: "2015-04-26 04:16:37">
        got: nil

   (compared using ==)
 # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:20:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.53769 seconds (files took 3.21 seconds to load)
3 examples, 1 failure, 1 pending

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:18 # User#favorited(post) returns the appropriate favorite if it exists
```

It looks like to me that the test is having an issue finding an id for the specified user. How would I go about locating and assigning the specified user's id?

Any ideas to lead me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: Please include your code for the `Favorite` model. Especially its associations.

Comment: Thank you for the response @Drenmi. I have added the Favorite Model showing its proper association.

Answer (score 0):

Let's have a look at your second test case:

```
it "returns the appropriate favorite if it exists" do
  favorite = Favorite.new
  expect( @user.favorite ).to eq( favorited(@post) )
end
```

Firstly, you need to `create` the `Favorite`, rather than just `new` it. Using `create` will save it to the database, which will allow `User#favorite` to find it.

Secondly, you need to associate the `Favorite` with your `User` and your `Post`.

```
favorite = Favorite.create(user: @user, post: @post)
```

(This assumes your `Favorite` model has `belongs_to` associations to `User` and `Post`.)

Next, let's look at your expectation. You might need to `reload` the `@user` model to make sure it picked up it's new `favorite`.

```
expect(@user.reload.favorite).to eq(favorited(@post))
```

Comment: Thank you for your help @Drenmi. This seems to have worked for the most part, but I am now receiving an error stating that it: "Couldn't find User with 'id'=" Is it having trouble locating an id for @user?

Comment: @bbear500: It could be an indication that your `@user` is not saved, and therefore does not have an `id` when you try to create your `Favorite`.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to test the following method:

```
class User < ActiveRecord:Base

  def favorited(post)
    ...
  end

end
```

Then I would recommend doing something like the following:

```
it "returns the appropriate favorite if it exists" do
  favorite = Favorite.create( user_id: @user.id, post_id: @post.id )

  expect( @user.favorited( @post ) ).to eq( favorite )
end
```

The exception reads as follows:

I expect the actual value, **@user.favorited( @post )**, to equal the expected value, **favorite**.  Thus, I would recommend following this patten when using the **expect** syntax:

```
expect( actual_value ).to eq( expected_value )
```

In this case, **actual_value** represents the result of executing the User#favorited under test (UT) and the **expected_value** represents what we think it should be prior to executing the test.  Lastly, I like to be explicit when passing arguments to **create** method because Rails tends to do these magical things that may not always be clear to reader of the code.